# Checking which of two column values is closest to a calculated value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Absolute rookie at SQL so apologies upfront if not possible or absurd.

Single table in SQL-Lite

First of all I want to filter the table to only return rows where the difference between decimal in column A and decimal in column B is more than 3

Then for each row I want to subtract integer in column C from integer in column D to give result E. And then I want to know whether the decimal in column A or decimal in column B is closer to result E

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Without those, your question lacks context.

Comment: "Single table in SQL-Lite" please provide it in the shape of several lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You have described what you want. Please show what you tried and explain the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to achieve what you want.

Comment: select x.E, resB - resA as result
from (select a.D-a.C as E, abs(a.A-(a.D-a.C)) as resA, abs(a.B-(a.D-a.C)) as resB
        from (select A, B, C, D, A-B as val1 
         from Table) a
       where a.val1 >3) x;  maybe this query can help? if result is positive than A is closer to E, otherwise B is closer to E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below basically uses a subquery to keep all the needed values handy, a CASE operator to make the decision, and the ABS() function to determine absolute distance.

```
select A, B, C, D, E,
  case when ABS(A-E) < abs(B-E) then 'A' else 'B' end [Closer_Value]
from (
  select A, B, C, D, (C-D) as [E]
  from YourTable
  where abs(A-B) > 3
) as Temp
```

Comment: You da man! I don't understand all this yet but it worked perfectly and I'll be unpacking it to learn how to do similar stuff going forwards. Thanks!